# Nancy server on Mono on Ubuntu stalls, many TIME_WAIT sockets

Tags: http, ubuntu, tcp, mono, nancy

One of our production stacks using `NancyFX` (self-hosted) on `Mono 4.2.3` on `Ubuntu 14.04` (on AWS EC2 behind an ELB) serves RESTful HTTP calls from external clients. The processing of those requests, in many occasions, also includes making HTTP calls to other services, database lookups and such.

With a certain amount of incoming requests on each machine (that seems to us the server *should* be able to handle gracefully), the servers start to stall, new incoming connections run into timeouts, etc.

Using `netstat`, we saw that there are thousands of sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state. We presume those are either cause or at least symptom of the problems we're having.

Does somebody with a similar setup have an idea how we could identify and fix the root cause of those problems?

We've experimented with varying methods of making HTTP requests in C#, mono startup parameters (`--server` and setting the number of threads per cpu to sensible amounts) already but could not stop the servers from stalling and degrading catastrophically.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I also run to a similar problem. In my case I use Windows 10 and I use NancyFX and connect to it from localhost, but still running `netstat` I can see many `TIME_WAIT` connections. After few minutes they are closed but it looks strange.